# Is there any other country than Germany with no speed limits?

Tags: legal, driving, where-on-earth, factoids

I'm very into road trips. Therefore I'm always looking for something special.

I think it is very special that at least parts of Germany's highways have no speed limits. But since I live very close to Germany this is not so special for me.

So I'm looking for any other country that has at least partly no speed limits on its roads. It would be great if it is in Europe or can be at least reached by car from Central Europe.

Comment: In France, you can drive as fast as you want. You even get certificates delivered by police.

Comment: @mouviciel What??? In Ile-de-France?

Comment: @mouviciel except on black saturday, when there's a million mobile roadblocks moving at a snail's pace :)

Comment: Go to philipoines there is no damn speed limit out there.!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not abou travel.

Comment: @AndréPeseur How is planning a road trip across Europe looking for roads with a specific criteria *not* about travel?!

Comment: The state of Montana, USA abolished its *daytime* speed limit (on interstate freeways) between 1995 and 1999.

Comment: There are also the technically correct but practically useless answers of countries which have no roads...

Comment: General comment: note that Germany *does* have speed limits on highways, there's just no *general* speed limit. That is, unless otherwise signaled, you can drive as fast as you want (and is safe), but a lot of the highways have stretches with a specific speed limit, so look our for the signs.

Comment: Germany doesn't have no speed limits. Some parts of Germany have no speed limits. There is a big difference between those two sentences.

Comment: It's a long way from Europe, but [Bali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bali) doesn't have a speed limit. That said the roads are tiny, packed, and in all kinds of conditions, so the practical driving speed is pretty low.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Our friends at Wikipedia have a page about [Speed Limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limit), on there is a section about '**Roads without speed limits**'. Besides the German Autobahns, the only other roads that are currently without speed limits are rural roads on the Isle of Man, but I doubt you can go really fast on them.

Comment: Oh - you can go really fast on the Isle of Man. There are even some straight bits. But the fun comes from the fact that you can go really fast on all those twists and turns. Much more exciting than autobahns, which while very functional, are boring to drive on.

Comment: The Northern Territory either had or still has no speed limit on open highways, but the catch is the police can pull you over for driving unsafely if you're going really fast. You then have to prove that you were in fact driving safely at that speed. A famous racing car driver once managed to do this using his years as a professional high speed driver as his evidence.

Comment: @hippietrail: I googled about the NT in response to this question. It seems to be in the past tense.

Comment: Some US states have no speed limit afaik, but most do which is why wikipedia probably doesn't mention the US.

Comment: The Isle of Mann is famous for it's motorcycle races on the streets. Campervans (or caravans) are banned there.

Comment: @jwenting, no, there are no longer any states w/o speed limits: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_the_United_States. Nevada used to be like that, though.

Answer (score 20):

It's not an entire country, but Australia's [**Northern Territory**](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Northern_Territory) had [no speed limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_Australia#Historical_limits) (on major highways) until 2007, and they're seriously considering going back to this -- not a bad idea, given that there's a whole lotta nothing out there.  For one year from February 2014, there's now [a 200-km section of highway north of Alice Springs with no limits](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-02-01/speed-limits-shelved-for-nt-highway-sports-cars/5232388), and [there are plans to expand this](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-04-08/nt-no-speed-limit-trial-to-be-expanded/5376402).

Comment: I traveled as a passenger on some of the roads in the Northern Territory and wondered whomever would be daring enough to do over 60km/h let alone over 100 km/h. Those roads were in pretty poor condition and not tarmacked. That was back in 2005.

Comment: Note that this seems to be no longer the case. Accroding to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_Australia#NT_open_speed_limits), speed limits in NT were returned on 20 November, 2016.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That's because the governing party changed, and they'll likely flip-flop again after the next election...

Answer (score 6):

I have driven in many countries around the world, from the beautiful Autobahns in Germany to the sandy highways of Saudi Arabia and I can tell you, you can drive as fast as you want in Saudi Arabia as you can in portions of the Autobahn in Germany.  If you are driving like a mad man (or woman), no one is going to chase you down in Saudi however, Germany, as with most European nations, have an awesome law enforcement system called "traffic camera"! which are portable (tripod, floor model, vehicle mounted, bridge mounted, man operated, etc...) that take your picture and send it to the address on your license (EU) with the fine!

Comment: "(or woman)" - are female drivers currently allowed in Saudi Arabia?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: according to Wikipedia "Saudi Arabia has no written ban on women driving, but Saudi law requires citizens to use a locally issued license while in the country. Such licenses are not issued to women, thus making it effectively illegal for women to drive. Furthermore, most Saudi scholars and religious authorities have declared women driving haram (forbidden)."

Comment: A co-worker of mine went on a business trip to Saudi Arabia in the late '90s.  He said that one of the major highways enters Riyadh in a roundabout/traffic circle.  He said that there is an ambulance permanently posted at the roundabout because there are frequent accidents caused by people who are unable to decelerate in time to enter the roundabout.

Comment: Saudi Arabia is in the midst of a major crackdown on speeding drivers. Most major highways have speed cameras now. Add to that some pretty hefty speeding fines and you have a much saner situation. I was there a few months ago, and while there are still a few speeders here and there, the situation is much improved.

Answer (score 0):

Andhra Pradesh,India. there are no specific [Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_India) for motorcycles and cars.As long as you have control of your vechicle,there are no charges applied,Law comes into action only if you hit someone and caught by any means.cameras appear at major cities(accident prone areas),but unless you cause any damage police won't look after you.no extra licence for higher cc bikes/cars."Rock n Roll"

Comment: That page says there is no **default** limit. That doesn't seem to mean there's no limit at all.

Answer (score -5):

There are roads in Montana that do not have speed limits. So we can add the US to the list.

[source](https://www.motorists.org/press/montana-no-speed-limit-safety-paradox/)

Comment: That site is badly out of date.  Montana eliminated their "reasonable and prudent" speed limit in 1999 as being legally impossible to enforce; as of October 2015, the highest permissible speed was [80 mph on some sections of Interstate](http://www.mdt.mt.gov/visionzero/roads/speedlimits.shtml).